# Use ffmpeg to modify single frame without remux?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, containers, video-processing, hashcode

I am curious of a fast way to modify a video, slightly, as to force the video to hash differently than the source. I want to avoid changes to meta tags, as these are parsed from the container file and not the video data itself.

I will be using a process to compare videos for analytical work, but the process requires the 2 inputs to have differing hashes for the video content (otherwise the analytical process yields odd results). I am testing an improvement on this process, and need to have very similar videos.

I have currently just used a ffmpeg bash script and filtered a VERY light 2x2 pixel for the first second of the video (90% transparent) and this seems to do the trick as they hash differently, but it requires demux / remux of the video, which takes forever if I want to analyze a lot of videos.

Is there a way, using ffmpeg, to simple modify a single frame (specified by a time value) and change a single pixel and just copy the rest of the video contents?

Comment: How are the hashes generated?

Comment: Using Md5 via command line (it also uses md5 internally for the video data that's contained)

Comment: So on the whole file, not the extracted video stream or per-frame?

Comment: And the filtering you did on the first second is a ffmpeg filter?

Comment: how about just cutting off a fraction of a second at start or end?

Comment: I manually compared MD5s, and this works for the analytics accepting it.

And yeah, I used an ffmpeg filter command. 

Hmm, That "could" work. Any way to just drop a single frame as to make it not noticeable?

Comment: Are you using ffmpeg to generate md5?  --- You can chop off the last frame more easily. Usually you can't remove just the first few frames. You have to remove the whole first GOP. when streamcopying.